# Plantuml, supertype/subtype generalization

Tags: plantuml

I am working on an object diagram and would like to use this kind of notation: [image]

To convey a disjoint. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your picture you have Entity-Relationship diagram, which has nothing to do with UML. Likewise UML Object diagram is concerned with visualizing actual instances, so my guess is that you were looking for Class Diagram.

In UML, you could model this as a generalization set

```
hide circle

class Patient

Patient <|-- Outpatient
Patient <|-- Resident


GeneralizationSet ..(Patient, Outpatient)
(Patient, Resident) .. GeneralizationSet

class GeneralizationSet {
  isDisjoint = true
}
```

[image]

the `isDisjoint = true` tells us that it can be either one or the other, but not both.